# No response from passport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

In the process of learning the MEAN stack I came across an issue.
Whenever I try to use passport authenticate method it never returns any response. I always get "localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

Here is the exact isolated code snippet that isn't working:

```js
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", 
{successRedirect: "/campgrounds", failureRedirect: "/login"}),
function(req, res){
});
```

If you want to see the whole code, you can find it: [HERE](https://github.com/AleksandarColovic/YelpCampRepo)

Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this line needs parens after authenticate](https://github.com/AleksandarColovic/YelpCampRepo/blob/master/app.js#L33)

according to the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local-mongoose#configure-passportpassport-local)

Comment: Yep. That fixed it.

Out of all the good reasons my code wouldn't work, I get the worst one: 
I didn't put the parentheses...

Thank you kind hero, for pointing this out. I would have never found it.
I spent like 2 hours trying to find the reason why it didn't work..